# Why are .htm files not displayed properly unless accessed from an actual website?

Tags: android, ipad, web-applications, mobile, webkit

I've tested with an iPad and a droid tablet. If I save the file on my desktop and then access it it doesn't get displayed right. However, if I upload the file to my website it does get displayed right.

By displayed right/wrong I mean the following:

DISPLAYED RIGHT

- supports viewport tag
- android's browser doesn't crop the page

DISPLAYED WRONG

- viewport tag is not supported
- android's browser does crop the page

Comment: External stylesheet? MIME-TYPE?

Comment: Not sure why an external stylesheet would make a difference but I am analyzing the differences between localhost and server responses. Good idea!

Comment: @PeeHaa  Now that you mention it, mimetype/content-type is probably it.  After a recent update of Firefox 3.6, it started acting differently with html files on localhost vs on an external webserver if the mimetype is missing (I'd created a simple webserver as an experiment and wasn't returning any headers at the time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a thorough looking at of the headers which were basically all coming back like this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2012 17:35:57 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 99342

Found that the pages worked right if I set up another virtual directory in iis and accessed them there. It turns out the problem had to do with the system putting the content into an iFrame before responding.